# Why does with ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1) work with a .saveas in the statement?

Tags: excel, vba, methods, save, with-statement

To preface, I am fairly intermediate with VBA. I'm curious as to why the following code works.

```
    Dim report_wb as Workbook, _
        str_savepath, str_reportname as String
    
    Set report_wb = ThisWorkbook
    str_savepath = environ("userprofile") + "\Downloads\"
    str_reportname = "Report_name.xlsx"
    
    
    With report_wb.Sheets(1)
    .Activate
    .Range("A1").Value = "Report Name"
    .SaveAs Filename:=str_savepath + str_reportname, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
    End With
```

I kinda stumbled across this one by accident because I was receiving a bug that there was an object needed and isolated it to the .Range("A1").Value = "Report Name" line, and added the .Sheets(1) to the beginning of the With Statement because there is only one sheet in the report I'm manipulating.

I am just curious as to why this works for the .SaveAs/.Save methods for the workbook or if this is the best method to use because I want to avoid any potential errors later on in my code as this one report creates 3 additional reports.

Comment: Because a `Worksheet` has a [`SaveAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.saveas) method?

Comment: Side Note: `str_finalsave` is not declared and `str_savepath` is not used. My intuition tells me `str_finalsave` was meant to be `str_savepath`

Comment: @Toddleson yes I just forgot to edit that variable. Thank you for pointing that out.